# Make all the images inside my flexbox equal in size but always fit the available width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my flexbox container. I need the following to be true:

1. Images inside should always have a width between 90 and 200px.
2. The images should all be equal in size at all points.
3. The images should take up the available space in width.

This code shows *almost* what I want. If you start at a window width of around 250px and increase it everything works as I want, until around 425px when the last image doesn't fit. Then it goes way larger than the rest. I understand why, I just can't figure out how to force it to be the same size as the other 3 images. I tried everything from flex-basis and flex in general but all I try always fails on some of my requirements.

```css
.pp-avatar-area {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.pp-avatar-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.pp-image-avatar-item {
  min-width: 90px;
  max-width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp-avatar-area">
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will a grid-based solution work for you?

Comment: Problematic `flex-grow: 1;` - This property specifies how much of the flex container's remaining space should be assigned to the flex item's main size. When the flex-container's main size is larger than the combined main size's of the flex items, the extra space is distributed among the flex items. Hence, the last div.

Comment: @Kameron, yes i know, that is the problem. But how do I solve it to make it work like I want? :D

Comment: @InSync, Not sure, I have not worked much with grid. Do you have a suggestion? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `display: grid`:

```css
.pp-avatar-area {
  display: grid;
  
  /* As many columns as possible, fill all remaining width. */
  /* Column width lies between 90px and 200px. */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(90px, 1fr));

  /* Same height for all rows. */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  
  gap: 0.5rem;
  
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 75%;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.pp-avatar-area {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(90px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  
  padding: 0.5rem;
  
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 75%;
}

.pp-image-avatar-item {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp-avatar-area">
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
  <div class="pp-image-avatar-item" style="background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/2a58d3da93af4340c17566c1d486ca68?s=400&d=robohash&r=x')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works exactly as I wanted it to!